# NestJS - Prisma Generated Type does not give the exact model type

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma

I am using NestJs with Prisma to create a simple marketplace application, but I got confused that Prisma does not generate a proper type for creating a query to input to the database.

Here's the `prisma.schema`

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Users {
  id               Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  username         String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  password         String    @db.VarChar(255)
  orders           Orders[]
  lastLogin        DateTime? @db.Timestamp(6)
  hashRefreshToken String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  roles            String[]  @default(["user"])
  createdAt        DateTime? @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  updatedAt        DateTime? @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
}

model Products {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String       @db.VarChar(255)
  description String       @db.Text()
  quantity    Int          @default(0) @db.Integer()
  price       Decimal      @default(0.00) @db.Decimal(10, 2)
  OrderItems  OrderItems[]
}

model Orders {
  id         Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId     Int          @db.Integer
  status     OrderStatus  @default(CART)
  price      Decimal      @default(0.00) @db.Decimal(10, 2)
  user       Users        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  OrderItems OrderItems[]
}

model OrderItems {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  orderId   Int      @db.Integer
  productId Int      @db.Integer
  quantity  Int      @db.Integer
  price     Decimal  @default(0.00) @db.Decimal(10, 2)
  order     Orders   @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
  product   Products @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
}

enum OrderStatus {
  CART
  PAID
}
```

I tried to create data that the query looks like this :

```
await this.prismaService.orders.create({
   userId: 1,
   status: 'CART',
   price: 0,
})
```

But the typescript gives me these warnings:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'userId' does not exist in type 'OrdersCreateInput'. Did you mean to write 'user'?
```

When I highlighted the `OrdersCreateInput` which was generated by Prisma it didn't have the `userId` property inside it :

```
type Prisma.OrdersCreateInput = {
    status?: $Enums.OrderStatus;
    price?: string | number | Prisma.Decimal | DecimalJsLike;
    user: Prisma.UsersCreateNestedOneWithoutOrdersInput;
    OrderItems?: Prisma.OrderItemsCreateNestedManyWithoutOrderInput;
}
```

I have tried using `prisma generate` and `prisma migrate dev` but it didn't do anything, or did I write the schema wrong?